# SSIS TargetServerVersion. 2016 and 2017 options are missing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working on a SSIS project in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.4. SSDT version 17.0.62207 is also installed. I need to install the project on SQL Server 2016. However, I am not getting that option
in the configuration sections. Only SQL Server 2017, SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server 2022 are available.

[image]

I also happen to have the 2016, 2019 and 2022 versions of SQL Server installed on my development machine. I am getting some standard errors that imply I have the incorrect deployment target
version as indicated by many other questions on stackoverflow.
However, I cannot implement the suggested answers as SQL Server 2016 is not available in the list
as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: SSIS extension for VS2022 is a preview version. It has some limitations including limited list of supported SSIS run-time versions.

Comment: My solution for now is that I installed VS 2017 and SSDT for that version of visual studio. I am now able to target SQL Server 2016

Comment: You cam install VS2019 any edition, and its *SQL Server Integration Services Projects* extension v.3.16. Such combination allows to target the following SSIS run-times: 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, and 2019.

Comment: The SSIS extension for VS2022 does not support SQL Server 2016 as target server version - only SQL Server 2017, 2019 and 2022 are supported.
(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/release-notes-integration-services-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)